# Make the order of edited or reopened questions depend on when the question was edited or reopened

Tags: feature-request

I noticed that if a question is edited or reopened then it goes to the home page, but then once it gets beyond the home page it gets back to the page it was at before being edited or reopened.

As it is right now once a question gets beyond the first few pages without an answer it will probably never get answered.

I think if a question gets edited or reopened once off the home page, instead of having the questions page number depend on when it was asked, it should depend on when it was edited or reopened instead of the order of when it was asked as questions on lower page numbers are easier to see and therefor more likely to get attention.

Comment: Are you changing the sort? You get to choose the sort type and it sounds like you’re looking at newest, which is based on when the question is asked. Sorting by “active” should show the same view as the front page with the addition of low-scoring questions.

Comment: @Catija I checked and found that I can change the sort type, but I think Recent Activity should be the default sort mode to make questions with new activity get more attention given that most users likely will have whatever the default sort mode as their sort mode.

Comment: The system remembers your sort choice. Which should be the default is... kinda something people will argue about until we’re all bonkers. There’s value in the newest sort, too, and since we already default active on the homepage, we default newest on the question page. It works.